# How to check null object in razor view editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, templates, razor

In my ViewModel I have created a property of type Object and from controller I am passing a value of that object type property. Now I have created a Editor template to handle that Object type. Here is my code for that:

```
   <div class="form-group">
         @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.testProp)
   </div>
```

Based on the value type this editor template is calling different types of editor templates(String,Date, int).
Now how can I handle null/empty string using editor template? If my Model.testProp is null then how can I call the editor template which returns empty TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `null` check and choosing which template to use, based on that?

Like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @if (Model.testProp != null)
     {
         // If not null; Use the correct template, based on the type
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.testProp)
     }
     else
     {
         // Otherwise print an empty text box
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.testProp)
     }
</div>
```

You can also use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.testProp)` in your `if` statement, to check against blank `string`s.

This way, when the `testProp` **is** `null`, an `<input type="text"...>` will be created, with the correct field name to match when you `POST` some values back to the controller.

Also, I don't know if it makes any difference, but I usually declare the predicate expression as `x => x.testProp` - I've used this in my sample above.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks James. This works.. Actually I tried the same way but it was giving me some error but right now it's working perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you @Developer. All the best for your project :) (and for the record it's "Geoff" :oP)